# Erro na instalação de um biblioteca no Python 3.6 no windows

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, biblioteca

Boa noite.
Minha pergunta é bem objetiva e direta.
Estou tentando instalar uma biblioteca no python 3.6 no windows 10 64 bits.
No entanto está aparecendo o seguinte erro :
[image: Este é o que aparece quando tento isntalar]

Para instalar estou usando o pip install pocketsphinx
a biblioteca é a pocketsphinx
tentei instalar com pacote mas não deu, aparece a mesma coisa.
HELP '-'.
Obrigado.

Comment: Você baixou as dependências? https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx#prerequisites
```You must have SphinxBase, which you can download from http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net. Download and unpack it to the same parent directory as PocketSphinx, so that the configure script and project files can find it. On Windows, you will need to rename 'sphinxbase-X.Y' (where X.Y is the SphinxBase version number) to simply 'sphinxbase' for this to work.```